# How to show SQL result based on dropdownlist selected item JSP

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to get a MYSQL result in a jsp page,The result is based on dropdownlist selected item.I need to add a function in the onChange() tag. Thanks in advance.

```
<select name="qab" onchange="">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">item1</option>
      <option value="2">Item2</option>
      <option value="3">Item3</option>
    </select>
    <%
   String qab=request.getParameter("qab");
   Connection conn=null;
   String query="SELECT addresse,nom_locataire FROM `Table1` WHERE m.qabid="+qab+"";
             Statement st=null;
             ResultSet rs=null;
     %>
                  <table>
             <%
             while(rs.next())
             {
                          %>    
                 <tr>
                    <td><%=rs.getString("nom_locataire") %></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString("addresse") %></td>
                 </tr>           
             <%

               conn.close();
               st.close();
               rs.close();
             }

             %>
       </table>
```

Comment: The only way to do it, using  your `programming style` is to put your `select` control inside of a `form` and trigger the `submit` event using javascript and the `onChange` event.

Comment: is there a way to show the resullt without submitting,I mean by just changing the dropdownlist values.what is the suitable fonction in the onChange tag.

Comment: Like I said before, not using that `procedural mixing client and server side programming style`

Comment: Are you at least working with `servlets`?

Comment: On change call to a JS function, do a ajax call to a servlet end point / another JSP page to the resultsets.

Comment: @Hackerman,i'm not using a servlet in this page.Thanks

Comment: @Senthil,Do you have a code of this JS function.?thanks

Comment: here an example is there with screen shots posted URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373444/populate-html-table-data-based-on-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-java

Comment: @Senthil ,thank you!